# Octal literals error in jquery definitions (typescript)

Tags: jquery, typescript, definitelytyped

My Project is written in Typescript and it gets compiled with ES5 mode. If I want include jquery from the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) then always get an Error in compile time:

```
path-to-project/jquery/jquery-tests.ts(24,17): error TS1085: Octal literals are not available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
```

I added jquery as usually:

```
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

Any idea how I can get rid of that error?

Comment: Paste your code to include jQuery.d.ts please.

Comment: I edited the message with the include

Comment: would you please some code

Comment: But the error is in `jquery-tests.ts`. Where are you including these file? And, why are you including the test?

Comment: @PedroGámez nuget must have added it

Comment: weird. when I delete the jquery-test files. everything works fine. probably the gulp task for compiling the code was calling the test file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in `jquery.d.ts` it is in the test file `jquery/jquery-tests.ts`.

Just delete the test file or exclude it from your Visual studio project.